# How to prevent items in a list returning "0" when not filled in and they supposed to be "null"?

Tags: c#, .net, list, model, null

This was kind of a hard question to ask but this is my problem:

I'm populating a grid with data I obtain from a different class, this class uses a (generic) Model that can represent multiple models:

Model(can represent Vessel or Container):

```
public class DataGridInstallationRow
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Vessel
    public int IMO { get; set; }
    public int MMSI { get; set; }
    public int EEOI { get; set; }
    public int FOC { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Total Fuel Mass")]
    public int TotalFuelMass { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Average Speed")]
    public int AverageSpeed { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Total Distance Sailed")]
    public int TotalDistanceSailed { get; set; }

    //Container
    [Display(Name = "Generated by Sun")]
    public int EnergyGeneratedBySun { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Generated by Wind")]
    public int EnergyGeneratedByWind { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Generated by Generator")]
    public int EnergyGeneratedByGenerator { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Consumed by EV's")]
    public int EnergyConsumedByEV { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Consumed by Construction Site")]
    public int EnergyConsumedByConstructionSite { get; set; }
}
```

This model is used in my provider:

```
        if (fleet.Type.Equals("Container"))
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new DataGridInstallationRow()
            {
                Name = $"Container {i}",
                EnergyGeneratedBySun = 13,
                EnergyGeneratedByWind = 19,
                EnergyGeneratedByGenerator = 3,
                EnergyConsumedByEV = 15,
                EnergyConsumedByConstructionSite = 24
            }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new DataGridInstallationRow()
            {
                Name = $"Vessel {i}",
                IMO = 231,
                MMSI = 1344,
                EEOI = 8121,
                FOC = 123,
                TotalFuelMass = 6817,
                AverageSpeed = 14,
                TotalDistanceSailed = 1560
            }).ToList();
        }
```

As u can see, depending on the Fleet.Type, one of the other is filled in. If Fleet.Type is container the object will look like this:

[image]

As u can see the properties of "Vessel" is filled in aswell with all "0", I want these to be null instead of "0" because my datagrid is filled with both models now:

[image]

Whats best practice to avoid and fix this?

**UPDATE**

Applied solution of Dogac:

```
if (fleet.Type.Equals("Container"))
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new DataGridInstallationRow()
            {
                Name = $"Container {i}",
                EnergyGeneratedBySun = 13,
                EnergyGeneratedByWind = 19,
                EnergyGeneratedByGenerator = 3,
                EnergyConsumedByEV = 15,
                EnergyConsumedByConstructionSite = 24
            }).Where(row =>
            {
                return row.EnergyGeneratedBySun.HasValue &&
                       row.EnergyGeneratedByWind.HasValue &&
                       row.EnergyGeneratedByGenerator.HasValue &&
                       row.EnergyConsumedByEV.HasValue &&
                       row.EnergyConsumedByConstructionSite.HasValue;
            }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new DataGridInstallationRow()
            {
                Name = $"Vessel {i}",
                IMO = 231,
                MMSI = 1344,
                EEOI = 8121,
                FOC = 123,
                TotalFuelMass = 6817,
                AverageSpeed = 14,
                TotalDistanceSailed = 1560
            }).Where(row =>
            {
                return row.IMO.HasValue &&
                       row.MMSI.HasValue &&
                       row.EEOI.HasValue &&
                       row.FOC.HasValue &&
                       row.TotalFuelMass.HasValue &&
                       row.AverageSpeed.HasValue &&
                       row.TotalDistanceSailed.HasValue;
            }).ToList();
        }
```

Is still not working, im again receiving a list with nullable items.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you precise the UI Framework that you use? WPF, UWP, WinForms, ...?

Comment: Im using SyncFusion Blazor for the grid but the DataSource needs to filter the items away that are not filled in

Comment: @Niels that doesn't really answer the question about "WPF, UWP, WinForms, ...?"

Comment: `int` _cannot_ be `null`. `int?` can. See [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)

Answer (score 2):

Try making all properties nullable.

Like this:

```
// Vessel
public int? IMO { get; set; }
public int? MMSI { get; set; }
public int? EEOI { get; set; }
public int? FOC { get; set; }
```

Edit regarding comment:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new DataGridInstallationRow()
            {
                Name = $"Vessel {i}",
                IMO = 231,
                MMSI = 1344,
                EEOI = 8121,
                FOC = 123,
                TotalFuelMass = 6817,
                AverageSpeed = 14,
                TotalDistanceSailed = 1560
            }).Where(row =>
            {
                return row.IMO.HasValue && 
                       row.MMSI.HasValue && 
                       row.EEOI.HasValue && 
                       row.FOC.HasValue && 
                       row.TotalFuelMass.HasValue && 
                       row.AverageSpeed.HasValue && 
                       row.TotalDistanceSailed.HasValue;
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes they are "null" now but how can i make this query so that nullable items are not in the list?:

return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new DataGridInstallationRow()
    {
     Name = $"Container {i}",
     EnergyGeneratedBySun = 13,
     EnergyGeneratedByWind = 19,
     EnergyGeneratedByGenerator = 3,
     EnergyConsumedByEV = 15,
     EnergyConsumedByConstructionSite = 24
    }).ToList();

Comment: @Niels Edited my answer, the Where operator in this query will filter out all rows that has any null properties. The lambda expression can be adjusted to your business needs.

Comment: Cant this be more dynamic? Like .Where(i => i != null?)

Comment: You can add a method that returns bool, something like this: `row => row.IsValid()` and implement `IsValid` in `DataGridInstallationRow`.

Comment: Im now using:

return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new DataGridInstallationRow()
    {
     Name = $"Vessel {i}",
     IMO = 231,
     MMSI = 1344,
     EEOI = 8121,
     FOC = 123,
     TotalFuelMass = 6817,
     AverageSpeed = 14,
     TotalDistanceSailed = 1560
    }).Where(row =>
    {
     return row.IMO.HasValue &&
         row.MMSI.HasValue &&
         row.EEOI.HasValue &&
         row.FOC.HasValue &&
         row.TotalFuelMass.HasValue &&
         row.AverageSpeed.HasValue &&
         row.TotalDistanceSailed.HasValue;
    }).ToList();

Dont work

Comment: Can u check? updated the bost with ur solution, list still returning nullable items.